# How to turn on change tracking for a particular table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, change-tracking

Is it possible to turn on change tracking for a particular table in PostgreSQL? I know that it can be easily done in MS SQL Server.

```
ALTER TABLE Person.Contact  
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

Do we have something similar in PostgreSQL? Is it possible to achieve the same behavior without creating triggers? I want to track all DML operations for a particular table.

Comment: you set set `log_statement = 'mod'` in `postgresql.conf`, but that tracks changes in all tables.

Comment: @richyen We also have `pg_last_commited_xact` that provides a value associated with the last commit, but I need to track changes of a small range of tables. In MS SQL Server we have `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION` and `CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION`. I'm looking for a similar feature in PostgreSQL.

Comment: There is no built in functionality for this. The closest I can come up with is `PGAudit`. See here [PGAudit] for docs.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver In MS SQL I used to copy all modified data starting from some particular version. I mean I have an old `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION` value which I compare with `CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION`. If I understand that the data is out-of-sync I copy it to another database. What it the best PostgreSQL analogue? Could you lead me on a trail?

Comment: I'm not really seeing an analogue. You could try [Logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/logical-replication.html) but that would have to be shaped to allow only some of the DML through e.g. `INSERT`, otherwise it would do as it says keep the replicas in sync. The issue would be there is no concept of version.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure that I follow you. Why do we need to shape DML? I need to track all of the changes like insert, update and delete.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think I explained my goal in a wrong way. I just want to run a procedure that will sync my the second database if the first and the second databases are out-of-sync. I don't need to implement some kind of real-time synchronization in a background process. I want to start synchronization when I need it. I want to do all the job by a single procedure call.

Comment: I have not used this [Ankane](https://github.com/ankane/pgsync) but it does do syncing. Then there is [SQL Workbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/) which as [Data Diff](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/compare-commands.html#command-data-diff).  Otherwise I know of no single procedure call solution.